# How to write a bitfield to an integer value?

Tags: c, bit-fields

I am trying to do this:

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t red : 6;
    uint16_t green : 5;
    uint16_t blue : 5;
} color_t
```

Then I would like to get something like:

```
color_t clr;
clr.red = 0;
clr.green = 10;
clr.blue = 15;
```

And write the compound variable clr to an int:

```
int value = clr; // this does not work

fprintf(draw, "%4X", value);
```

The reason I am doing this is I want to create colors like orange, purple and so on and draw them on the screen from a file.
Inside a file I am writing a color in hex format.

One another thing is that I'd like to do this later in my code:

```
if (clr == value) { ... }
```

Or in another words, I'd like to compare the values from struct bitfield and int holding the real hex value of the color.

Comment: Make a `union` of  `color_t` and `uint16_t`. Note, that the bitfield layout is not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a stand-alone example showing how to use a union to access the value of a struct with bit fields:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    uint16_t red: 6;
    uint16_t green: 5;
    uint16_t blue: 5;
} color_t;

typedef union {
    uint16_t color_value;
    color_t color_bits;
} color_helper_t;

int main(void) {
    color_helper_t clr;

    clr.color_bits.red = 0;
    clr.color_bits.green = 0;
    clr.color_bits.blue = 15;

    uint16_t value = clr.color_value;

    printf("%04X\n", value);

    if (clr.color_value == value) {
        printf("The values are equal\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
7800
The values are equal
```

Comment: If you propose a solution like this, you should mention that this relies on implementation defined behavior. This code is not portable.

Answer (score 3):

I think your best option is to write a simple converter function like this:

```
uint16_t colorToInt(color_t c)
{
    uint16_t ret = 0;
    ret |= c.blue;
    ret |= c.green << 5;
    ret |= c.red << 10;
    return ret;
}
```

Then you can simply do

```
int value = colorToInt(clr);
```

And here is the inverse:

```
color_t intToColor(uint16_t x)
{
    color_t ret = {
        .blue = 0 | x,
        .green = 0 | x >> 5,
        .red = 0 | x >> 10
    };
    return ret;
}
```

Side note: Avoid using identifiers ending with `_t`. They are reserved by the POSIX standard. I would also advice against using `typedef`s unless you are creating a library with completely opaque objects.

Comment: I agree with your solution, but I was searching for a different way.

Comment: @Amaterastis Note that this solution might seem overcomplicated, but in fact it is more portable than `union` one. As I have mentioned before, the bitfelds layout is not guaranteed by C standard, while this code has a perfectly defined behavior on any platform.